# Affine decipher wrong output

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption

There is failed Affine decipher code the problem is that I am getting a totally wrong output.

```
public class AffineCipherDecryption {

public void Affine(int a, int b, JTextComponent Message, JTextComponent DisplayResult){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int len = Message.getText().length();
        BigInteger dda = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
        BigInteger dd = dda.modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(26));
            int bb = dd.intValue();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){

          char currentChar = Message.getText().charAt(i);

          char finalChar = (char) ((bb*(currentChar - 'A') - b) % 26 + 'A');


           builder.append(finalChar);

         }

        String result = builder.toString().toLowerCase();


        DisplayResult.setText(result);


}
```

}

I modiffied it but still the output si wrong...

Comment: `1/a` is always `0` (unless `a` is `1` or `-1`)

Comment: [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) is the key concept in Affine Cipher..correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: boxed__l thanks for openning my eyes